# How to change img to div in waterwheelCarousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to change img element in [waterwheelCarousel](http://code.google.com/p/proyectofinalingles/source/browse/trunk/js/jquery.waterwheelCarousel.js?r=7)

I have tried to replace img with div in .js/.css

so my html look like :

```
<div id="waterwheel-carousel-default">
      <div class="carousel-controls">
        <div class="carousel-prev"></div>
        <div class="carousel-next"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-images">

   <div style="background-image:url('images/testImage1.png')">hhhhh</div>
   <div style="background-image:url('images/testImage1.png')">hhhhh</div> 
   <div style="background-image:url('images/testImage1.png')">hhhhh</div> 
   <div style="background-image:url('images/testImage1.png')">hhhhh</div>     

      </div>
 </div>
```

My Js file I have replace every :

```
    $(this).find(".carousel-images img").length 
   itemsContainer.find('img')
```

Respectively with:

```
    $(this).find(".carousel-images > div").length
    itemsContainer.find('div')
```

but it dosen't work any one can help?

Comment: Are your trying to change a background image of DIV element? Then you should use css() jquery function.

Comment: @MarcinBuciora the original carousel used <img> instead of <div> in html I want to change <img> by <div> because i want to add some elements to carousel